# Discord JS Returning Undefined When Fetching Member

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch specific server members by their user id so I can assign a particular role to them. But everytime I get undefined response.

This bot has adminstrator permission and I assigned all required intents. But still no success.

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ],
})
```

Fetching member

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
console.log(guild)
const member =  guild.members.cache.get(owner_id)
console.log(member)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled intents in the [Discord Developer Console](https://discord.com/developers) as well?

Comment: @node_modules Yes. https://prnt.sc/vtqHrGwPNMKO

Comment: In the code you're not fetching a member, you're checking the cache to see if they are there. Fetching would be `guild.members.fetch(owner_id)` and resolving the promise

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine. The only thing, is that you are missing the `GuildPresences` intent as well, since the presences are part of the `GuildMember` collection. If that one is missing, the entire collection will return `undefined`. I tried using your code, and indeed received `undefined` for the `member` variable.

So, adding the following intent to the list of client intents, this should work:

```js
GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
```

To get the presence intent to work, double check if you have enabled the presence intent in the [Discord Developer Console](https://discord.com/developers) as well.